# Proving $ C \subset A$ and $D \subset B \rightarrow C\cap D\subset A \cap B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How would I show the following?

Proposition

$C \subset A$ and $D \subset B \rightarrow C\cap D\subset A \cap B$

**Attempt:**

Let x any object.

$x\in C \rightarrow x \in A$

As A contain C

$x \in D \rightarrow x\in B$

As B contains D.

if $x \in  C\cap D$

Then x is in C and x is in D.

And since A contain C. B contain D.

$x\in C\cap D$ then $x \in A \cap B$

Comment: I'd say that $C \cap D \subset C \subset A$ and the same thing for $B$, but that's your call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $x \in C \cap D$ then it follows that $x \in C \subset A$ and $x\in D \subset B$ hence that $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ therefore
$$x \in A\cap B$$

But this is true for any $x \in C \cap D$ hence $C \cap D \subset A \cap B$, as desired.

Comment: In light of @mm-aops comment:
One may also apply the result of [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539320/a-subset-c-implies-a-cap-c-subset-b-cap-c?rq=1) for to each set respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can also divide the proof into smaller steps (as was already suggested in [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840019/proving-c-subset-a-and-d-subset-b-rightarrow-c-cap-d-subset-a-cap-b/840024#comment1733429_840024)). You can try to prove first the following:

> **Claim.** If $X\subseteq Y$, then $X\cap Z\subseteq Y\cap Z$.

Now if you know that $C\subseteq A$ and $D\subseteq B$, you can use the claim twice to get:
$$
C\cap D \subseteq A\cap D\\
A\cap D \subseteq A\cap B
$$
(In the first one we used the clam for $X=C$, $Y=A$ and $Z=D$; in the second one we used it for $X=D$, $Y=B$ and $Z=A$.)

If you know that "subset relation" (inclusion) is transitive (see [here](http://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subset_Relation_is_Transitive) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402826/inclusion-of-sets-transitive)), i.e., that $X\subseteq Y \land Y\subseteq Z \Rightarrow X\subseteq Z$; you get 
$$
C\cap D \subseteq A\cap B.
$$